# How to set Decimal Value in a Dataset in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview, dataset

I have a Column AMOUNT_PAISE in Dataset. I'm binding this dataset from the result set coming from sql server stored procedure. for AMOUNT_PAISE  column in DB currency is in paise(lets say 888 paise for a particular row) but I want to display this amount in Rupees(Rupee equivalenof 888 paise is 8.88). But I can not directly assign it, because dataset contains int64 values. when I convert decimal 888 to int64 it gives 9 (888/100 = 8.88 and when converted to int64 it gives 9)
So Please tell me what should I try now.

formula to convert from paise to rupee.

```
rupee = paise/ 100; //upto 2 decimal points

if (dsTransactionLogs.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    if (dsTransactionLogs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        //Code to convert amount from Paise to Rs.
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dsTransactionLogs.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            decimal decimalAmountInPaise = Convert.ToDecimal(dsTransactionLogs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AMOUNT_PAISE"]);
            decimalAmountInPaise = Math.Round(decimalAmountInPaise / 100, 2);
            //Int64 int64AmountInPaise = Convert.ToInt64(decimalAmountInPaise);
            string strAmount = decimalAmountInPaise.ToString("#.##");
            dsTransactionLogs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AMOUNT_PAISE"] = Convert.ToInt64(strAmount);
            i++;

        }

        GridViewTRANSACTIONDETAILS.DataSource = dsTransactionLogs;
        GridViewTRANSACTIONDETAILS.DataBind();
        transactionGVDiv.Style.Add("height", "400px");
        //LabelNoTransactionLogsID.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //LabelNoTransactionLogsID.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

this is aspx code for this column in gridview.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Amount"> 
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="AmountLbl" NavigateUrl="#" Text='<%#Eval("AMOUNT_PAISE") %>'> ></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do the conversion when displaying, rather than attempting to modify the DataTable.  I.e. replace:

```
... Text='<%#Eval("AMOUNT_PAISE") %>'> ...
```

by something like:

```
... Text='<%#  (Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("AMOUNT_PAISE")) / 100M).ToString("N2") %>'> ...
```

Comment: getting exeption Specified cast is not valid

Comment: Try Convert.ToDecimal instead of casting - see update.  It would probably also work by casting first to long then decimal - "(decimal)(long)Eval(...)"

Comment: In GridView its not displaying correct value.
But When I'm writing this in Code its working fine.

Decimal decimalValue = 888;
string tempStr = (Convert.ToDecimal(decimalValue) / 100).ToString("N2");

Answer (score 0):

Just Change you line :

```
 dsTransactionLogs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AMOUNT_PAISE"] = Convert.ToInt64(strAmount);
```

to

```
dsTransactionLogs.Tables[0].Rows[i]["AMOUNT_PAISE"] = strAmount;
```