# Dataset data not showing .00 decimals

Tags: asp.net

I have a table data like as shown below.

```
EmpID   Salary
123     350.00
124     450.000
```

I am taking same into dataset using dataadapter. When i observe data in dataset salary is showing as `350` and `450` without decimals i.e `.00`.

I want to consider `.00` also in dataset. Please help.

Comment: Whether you salary field on database is decimal or nvarchar ?

Comment: Salary data type is NUMBER(23,3) and am using oracle and my gridview does not contain bound fields. what ever the columns that get from dataset directly bind to gridview.

Comment: Try by adding .tostring("#.##"). in your final output. It will show your expected result.

Comment: See what .net provides: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx that is all

Comment: Or For more fine tuned control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Perhaps show an example of your gridview markup. The data is fine as it is, leave it alone. Leave it up to the Web Layer to decide how to display it.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this,

Here am just explaining you with some sample thing.

```
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string str = dr.GetInt32(1).ToString("#.##");
```

Replace String(str) with dataset as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [How to set Decimal Value in a Dataset in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619975/how-to-set-decimal-value-in-a-dataset-in-c)

```
Text='<%#  (Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("SALARY"))).ToString("N2") %>'>
```

Comment: This has to be one of the most convoluted ways to do it.